# file R/W activity monitoring

Tags: windows

I need some convenient small tool for 
checking some current activities over files in system
(windows I mean) by activity I do understand reads 
from files and writes done to files. Is there some 
such tool, preferably the best one of them ;-)

I would like to check such things as which files, 
some program 'touches' for read and write and things
like that.

much tnx

EDIT 
I ve checked Pcocess MOnitor and it is working but 
it gives just thousands of 'events' on every seconds -
Can filter it by process name and event types but even then 
there is much too more of it. I will be using it but maybe
someone knows something more convenient/simplest - the basic
info I need is what process touches which files not neccessary 
raw billions of messy system events

Answer (score 2):

**ProcMon** or **Process Monitor** will tell you all about your processes.

**RegMon** or **Registry Monitor** will tell you all about your registry keys.

**InControl** will give you the log file of every changes that has been done after a software installation or uninstallation.

Steps to use these tools:: [RegMon Or File Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758606%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You want Microsoft's [*Process Monitor*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645);

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity

(Poke around the site for lots of other auditing utilities)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of diagnostic tools available from Microsoft for this sort of thing. To monitor file activity, you could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), for example (it can also monitor registry access, amongst other things).

Answer (score 1):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is great to watch file access interactively (ie by a human).  If you need to monitor file access and run reports, etc, then [PA File Sight](http://www.poweradmin.com/File-Sight) works great.